# Pythonic Name-Value pairs to Dictionary Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an array of dicts of name–value pairs, what is the most effective or most Pythonic method for converting them to a dictionary with the names as keys and and values as the values?

Here's what I've come up. It's pretty short and seems to work fine, but is there some built-in function for doing just this sort of thing?

```
verbose_attributes = [
    {
        'Name': 'id',
        'Value': 'd3f23fa5'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'first_name',
        'Value': 'Guido'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'last_name',
        'Value': 'van Rossum'
    }]

attributes = {}

for pair in verbose_attributes:
    attributes[pair['Name']] = pair['Value']

print(repr(attributes))
# {'id': 'd3f23fa5', 'first_name': 'Guido', 'last_name': 'van Rossum'}
```

In short, is there a better way of converting `verbose_attributes` to `attributes`?

Comment: You can pass a set of `(key, value)` tuples to the `dict` constructor. I think you're looking for `dict(((x['Name'], x['Value']) for x in verbose_attributes))`. **Edit**: Another option is `dict(x.values() for x in verbose_attributes)`

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with what you have, personally. It's readable and gets the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dictionary-comprehension:

```
attributes = {x['Name']: x['Value'] for x in verbose_attributes}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` and `dict.values`

```
>>> dict(map(dict.values, verbose_attributes))
{'id': 'd3f23fa5', 'first_name': 'Guido', 'last_name': 'van Rossum'}
```

Yet another way using `map` and `operator.itemgetter`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dict(map(itemgetter('Name', 'Value'), verbose_attributes))
{'first_name': 'Guido', 'last_name': 'van Rossum', 'id': 'd3f23fa5'}
```

Comment: Not the way I would do it, but an interesting approach.

Comment: @nosklo. Since you said that it looks ugly. I came up with another method :)